# Am I using JQuery's autocomplete correctly? How much data can it handle?

Tags: jquery, flask

My html is

```
<form style="display: inline;" action="{{ url_for('autocompresults') }}" method="post" name="search">
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
{{ form.autocomp.label }}: {{ form.autocomp }}
<button class = "btn " type="submit" >Search</button>
</form>

<script>
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url_for("autotestGETTER") }}'
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#myautocomplete').autocomplete({
                source: data.json_list,
                minLength: 1,
                 select: function(event, ui) {
        //assign value back to the form element
        if(ui.item){
            $(event.target).val(ui.item.value);
        }
        //submit the form
        $(event.target.form).submit();
    }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

In my `views.py` I have

```
@app.route('/autotestGETTER', methods=['GET'])
def autotestGETTER():
    res=[]
    products = models.Product.query.all()
    for p in products:
        res.append(p.title)
    return jsonify(json_list=res)
```

This is working correctly as is. I have about 20,000 rows in my `Product` table. Is this excessive? I will have the autocomplete form on a navbar as part of my base, so every page will essentially trigger a call to get **all** the results of that table?

Before I began to implement this I assumed the data lookup would only occur once a few characters were entered and that the query would filter according to those characters. But it looks like JQuery's autocomplete function actually does the filtering?

Comment: for how many rows its working??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a server point of view this is not optimal at all but it can handle it without problems.

But from a client's point of view this could be a problem. Imagine a mobile device. Dealing with a JSON parsing of 20k rows would be cpu intensive and the webpage will be slow.

I don't know the plugin you're using but, usually, autocomplete works by sending the characters in the input field (using a parameter named `q`) and the server will respond with the search results, usually trimmed at a reasonable size, say 100 elements or less.

PS: a tip, you can optimize your result list a little using list-comprehension: `res = [p.title for p in products]`

Comment: That's what I thought. I'd like to make it work for partially enter data, but I can't seem to get it to work. The current version of my code only calls `autotestGETTER()` when the page loads. Don't I need that function to get called when there are changes to the`#myautocomplete` input form? Also, I don't think there is a `q` parameter with this pluging. But I think the equivalent is `term` based on [this](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: @theGman yeah, reading that page suggests you can pass a `function (req, respcbk) {}` to the `source` property. In that function you can request the result list from the server (you're right, it'll be the `req.term` parameter) and call the `respcbk` function with your results filtered server-side.